# NetOffice-Read word document as HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. C# programming language; .NET framework 4.0
For reading word documents, I'm using NetOffice  1.5.1.2 libraries.
In my controller:

```
       NetOffice.Factory.Initialize();
        // open word and an existing document
        NetOffice.WordApi.Application wordApplication = new  NetOffice.WordApi.Application();
        NetOffice.WordApi.Document newDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(@"C:\myWordFile.docx");

        // read text of document
        string text= newDocument.Content.Text;

        // close word and dispose reference 
        wordApplication.Quit();
        wordApplication.Dispose();
```

But, text is just plain text. What I need to have is HTML text for display in the browser exactly the same format in word document. Include tables, fonts,...
I don't know how to do it. Any help,Please!
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

[NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) uses COM under the hood and is thus subject to the same limitations as Interop - **which is [according to Microsoft NOT SUPPORTED in ASP.NET etc.](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2) !**

You can use use other libraries like [OpenXML from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) (free) or [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx) (commercial) which do not rely on Office and are fully supported in server-scenarios like yours.